# Minimum bottleneck spanning tree vs MST

Tags: python, algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree

*A MST(minimum spanning tree) is necessarily a MBST(minimum bottleneck spanning tree).*

Given a set of points in a 2D plane with the edges of the weight of the Euclidean distance between each pair of point, I want to find the minimum bottleneck edge in the spanning tree (the maximum-weighted edge).

According to my limited knowledge in this field and research on the internet, the best way to calculate this using the MST approach is to do a Delaunay triangulation of the given points, and use the fact that the MST of these points is a subset of the triangulation and then run Kruskal's or Prim's algorithm. Then all I need to do is to find the maximum weight in the MST.

I am wondering if I can do this more efficiently by building a MBST, as I am only looking for the bottleneck edge.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: my current way to find it, both using MST or MBST calculates the weight of all `V * (V-1) / 2` edges first, which I consider quite inefficient. I'd like to know if there's an alternative around this.

Comment: Certainly not on the real RAM, where Theta(n log n) is a tough benchmark. (1D MBST is equivalent to sorting.) In practice? Maybe.

Comment: Is this question actually about avoiding the implementation complexity of Delaunay? If so, I sympathize.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat or just to know if there's any alternative. Delaunay worked fine, it's just I fear I'm over complicating things.

Comment: I don't think you're overcomplicating things. There's a literature on EMST in higher dimensions that might scale down, including an algorithm by Bentley and Friedman that's heuristically O(n log n) (but quadratic in the worst case). I'm not familiar with it though.